# trying to run angular commend the terminal don't recognize the command

Tags: angular-cli

while trying to run a simple commend in terminal-command prompt " ng serve "
I get the next message:
`'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Install the CLI globally:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

or add a script in your package.json file inside the scripts object, like

```
"start": ng serve
```

and then, run the below command from terminal

```
npm run start
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help, when I try to write npm i -g @angular/cli in the cmd (I try to run it in the terminal - powershell and command prompt) and its didn't work

Comment: in both its say that npm isnt recognized

Comment: Do you have nodejs installed? To check, run node -v command on terminal. If you get an error, install nodejs and npm will also be installed.